# Transform an object recursively in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, function, recursion

I've been struggling with that problem for a few days. I have to transform an object into another object with a different structure.

from this:

```
{
  "a1" : "key",
  "a2" : {
    "b1" : "key",
    "b2" : {
      "c1" : "key"
    }
  }
}
```

to this:

```
{
  "key" : {
    "a1" : null,
    "a2" : [
      { 
        "b1" : null,
      },
      {
        "b2" : [
          "c1" : null
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

For better understanding, `a1`, `a2`, `b1`, `b3` etc. would represent css selectors. `null` will be the value applied to the node. But for now, this shouldn't matter.

My current (non working) function looks like this:

```
var json = {};
var obj = {};

function build(objA){
  for(var a in objA){
    var key = objA[a]; 

    if(key instanceof Object){
      obj = {}; obj[a] = key;
      build(key);
    } else {
      json[key] = json[key] || {};

      if(obj == undefined){
        json[key][a] = null;
      } else {
        var p = firstKeyOf(obj);
        var key = obj[p][a];
        json[key][p] = json[key][p] || [];

        var selector = {};
        selector[a] = null;

        json[key][p].push(selector);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

which produces:

```
{
  "key" : {
    "a1" : null,
    "a2" : [
      {
        "b1" : null
      }
    ],
    "b2" : [
      {
        "c1" : null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What did i miss? I appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Well, for starters, your outermost object needs to be processed differently from any inner objects.

Comment: Well, still dont get it right...

Comment: I think you'll need two functions, eg `build()` and `buildsub()`, where the former calls the latter, and the latter is recursive (calls itself). I'm guessing your current `build()` would then be fine except that the current recursive call would instead call `buildsub()`, but I'm not sure.

Comment: This is actually what i'm trying to implement now, a second recursive function. However, will see how it goes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
var Converter = (function() {

var pic;

function _rec(a, o) {
    for(var k in o){
        var s = o[k];
        var arr = a.slice();
        arr.push(k);
        if (s instanceof Object) { _rec(arr, s); }
        else {
            if ("string" == typeof s) { arr.unshift(s); _attach(pic, arr); }
            else console.log('Invalid key type');
        }
    }
}

function _attach(p, m) {
    var k = m.shift(); 
    if ( ! p.hasOwnProperty(k)) p[k] = (m.length == 0) ? null : {};
    if (m.length > 0) p[k] = _attach(p[k], m);
    return p;
}

function _reverse(obj) { 
    if ( ! (obj instanceof Object)) console.log('First parameter need to be an Object'); 
    else { pic = {}; _rec([], obj); return pic; }
    }
return {
    reverse: _reverse,
    attach: _attach
}
})();
```

Comment: Hey! I tried it and it seems to do what i want. I will take a closer look tomorrow. thx!